# JSF Primefaces error after failed validation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a strange behaviour with `Primefaces 4.0 / JSF 2.1` on `Tomcat 6`.
I have a pretty complex input form with various validations on fields. If the user submits the form and validation fails, parts of the page become unresponsive.

The strange thing is that some parts remain fully functional, while others (in the same component, accessing the same bean value) are broken.

**Here's an Example:**

**Backing beans:**

```
public class Config{

    private boolean enabled;
    private String  deu; 


    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getCra_deu() {
        return cra_deu;
    }

    public void setCra_deu(String cra_deu) {
        this.cra_deu = cra_deu;
    }
}

public class Contact {
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Now I have a JSF-Page with a panel configured like this:**

```
<p:panel id="pspanel" style="width:80%;" styleClass="#{bean.config.enabled?'activePanel':''} EditPanel" toggleable="true" collapsed="#{!bean.config.enabled}" widgetVar="pspanelVar" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="ps_enabled" style="margin-right:20px;" value="#{bean.config.enabled}" >
            <f:ajax render="pspanel" onevent="reapplyDefaults" />                   
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <p:outputLabel value="PS"/>
        </f:facet>  
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;" columnClasses="input-col1,input-col2">
        <p:outputLabel value="DEU:"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="ps_deu" value="#{bean.config.deu}" style="width:20em" styleClass="DefaultEnabled">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="none" itemValue=""/>               
            <f:ajax listener="#{controller.changed}" immediate="true" onevent="reapplyDefaults"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>          
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

**What should normally happen:** If the user clicks on the checkbox in the panel header, the backing beans `enabled-Value` will be set to true, the panel gets rerendered and this will get the style-class `activePanel` and it will be expanded (`collapsed=false`). This works normally.

**What happens after failed validation:** After validation failed, when the user clicks on the checkbox, the backing beans `enabled-Value` is correctly set and the panel gets the `style-class`, but it doesn't expand/collapse anymore. Which is really strange, because both the `style-class` and the `collapsed-attribute` use the same value in the backing bean (`config.enabled`).

I'd be very grateful for any ideas or suggestions on how to fix this or why this is happening. Thanks!

Comment: Do you see any error on the browser console?

Comment: @Tiny No. Neither the Chrome console nor the debug log of the server give any indication of what's going wrong..

Comment: Insist upon using if necessary, `<p:ajax>` (thus not `<f:ajax>`) inside `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` and `<p:selectOneMenu>`.

Comment: @Tiny Changed `<f:ajax render="pspanel" onevent="reapplyDefaults" /> ` to `<p:ajax update="pspanel" oncomplete="reapplyDefaults" />` and did the same for the selectOneMenu, but sadly the behaviour didn't change.

Comment: Does it work if the form is made valid afterwards? Tried `immediate=true` for 1st ajax for `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` ?

Comment: @opfau Sadly neither works. The only option I found so far is to manually trigger a full page reload after validation failed. Even a submit with ajax="false" doesn't work..